# Deriving Publisher from different publishers in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I have a property with a fixed type

```
var statusPublisher: Published<Status>.Publisher
```

and some other statuses like `substatus1`, `substatus2`

and I want it to combine values of other statuses like

```
var statusPublisher: Published<Status>.Publisher {
    $substatus1.combineLatest($substatus2).map { s1, s2 -> Status in ... }
}
```

but it says `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.CombineLatest<Published<Substatus1>.Publisher, Published<Substatus2>.Publisher>' to return type 'Published<Status>.Publisher'`

I managed to workaround it with one extra

```
var connectionStatusSubject = PassthroughSubject<Status, Never>()
```

that I put into

```
var connectionStatusPublisher: AnyPublisher<Status, Never> {
    connectionStatusSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

with new `AnyPublisher` here, but it seems not so neat.

Is there any way to make it the right way?

Comment: The problem is that generics are not covariant. `Published<Status>`, `Published<Substatus1>`, and `Published<Substatus2>` are totally unrelated types. I would suggest abandoning the substatus idea (or explaining what you are _really_ trying to do by having it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Published<T>.Publisher` is just a specific type of a publisher, created by `@Published` property wrapper. There's no reason at all to use that as the type of the computed property.

Type-erase to `AnyPublisher` - like you did with `PassthroughSubject` - except you don't need a `PassthroughSubject`:

```
var statusPublisher: AnyPublisher<Status, Never> {
    $substatus1
       .combineLatest($substatus2)
       .map { s1, s2 -> Status in ... }
       .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```